# hello world Android App crashes on Akaso tablet but not on glaxyS3 phone?

Tags: android, delphi, crash, delphi-xe5

iv been writing a few Android apps using Xe5 and they all have worked perfectly on Galaxy S3 recently bought a Akaso DTA90 tablet running Android 4.2.2 all the apps that worked on galaxy S3 crash on launch ? Any ideas why this may be ? possibly a Resolution issue ?

I have even tried a basic hello world app and that crashes also

My androidmanifest contans

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.embarcadero.tabtest2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="tabtest2" 
        android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="tabtest2"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="tabtest2" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
    </application>
</manifest>   
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Using LogCat i get the following

```
    I/SurfaceFlinger( 1083): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer
I/ActivityManager( 1935): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.
intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=com.embarcadero.testapp cmp=com.emb
arcadero.testapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity bnds=[342,142][410
,222]} from pid 3097
D/audio_hw_primary( 1086): start_output_stream: card:0, port:0, rate:44100
V/alsa_pcm( 1086): pcm_open_req, playback card: 0, device: 0, req_rate: 44100
V/alsa_pcm( 1086): pcm_open_req try rate: 44100
V/alsa_pcm( 1086): pcm_open_req OK config->rate: 44100
I/ActivityManager( 1935): Start proc com.embarcadero.testapp for activity com.em
barcadero.testapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity: pid=7014 uid=100
65 gids={50065, 1028}
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1083): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1083): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer
I/dalvikvm( 7014): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9..
.
I/qtaguid ( 1935): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10065) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 1935): setKernelCountSet(10065, 1) failed with
errno -1
E/Trace   ( 7014): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
W/ContextImpl( 7014): Unable to create external files directory
V/TabletStatusBar( 2453): setLightsOn(true)
I/ActivityManager( 1935): Process com.embarcadero.testapp (pid 7014) has died.
I/qtaguid ( 1935): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10065) res=-1 errno=1
W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 1935): setKernelCountSet(10065, 0) failed with
errno -1
I/WindowState( 1935): WIN DEATH: Window{4140e350 u0 com.embarcadero.testapp/com.
embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}
D/Zygote  ( 1084): Process 7014 exited cleanly (217)
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1083): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer
W/BufferQueue( 1083): freeAllBuffersLocked called but mQueue is not empty
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1083): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer
W/InputMethodManagerService( 1935): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain
of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4125bce8 attribute=n
ull, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41380338
W/WindowManager( 1935): Rebuild removed 5 windows but added 4
W/WindowManager( 1935): This window was lost: Window{4140e350 u0 com.embarcadero
.testapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity EXITING}
W/WindowManager( 1935): mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{4145d470 7014:u0a10065} mC
lient=android.os.BinderProxy@40fddb98
W/WindowManager( 1935): mOwnerUid=10065 mShowToOwnerOnly=true
W/WindowManager( 1935): mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#110 ty=1 fl
=#8010100 pfl=0x8 fmt=4 wanim=0x1030001}
W/WindowManager( 1935): Requested w=480 h=764 mLayoutSeq=4003
W/WindowManager( 1935): mBaseLayer=21000 mSubLayer=0 mAnimLayer=21000+0=21000 mL
astLayer=21025
W/WindowManager( 1935): mToken=AppWindowToken{41bc5f08 token=Token{4118b1d0 Acti
vityRecord{41087ea0 u0 com.embarcadero.testapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNat
iveActivity}}}
W/WindowManager( 1935): mRootToken=AppWindowToken{41bc5f08 token=Token{4118b1d0
ActivityRecord{41087ea0 u0 com.embarcadero.testapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FM
XNativeActivity}}}
W/WindowManager( 1935): mAppToken=AppWindowToken{41bc5f08 token=Token{4118b1d0 A
ctivityRecord{41087ea0 u0 com.embarcadero.testapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMX
NativeActivity}}}
W/WindowManager( 1935): mViewVisibility=0x0 mHaveFrame=true mObscured=true
W/WindowManager( 1935): mSeq=0 mSystemUiVisibility=0x0
W/WindowManager( 1935): mGivenContentInsets=[0,0][0,0] mGivenVisibleInsets=[0,0]
[0,0]
W/WindowManager( 1935): mConfiguration={0.95 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw640dp w640dp
 h1018dp 120dpi lrg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.49}
W/WindowManager( 1935): mHasSurface=true mShownFrame=[0.0,0.0][480.0,764.0] isRe
adyForDisplay()=false
W/WindowManager( 1935): mFrame=[0,0][480,764] last=[0,0][480,764]
W/WindowManager( 1935): mSystemDecorRect=[0,0][480,764] last=[0,0][480,764]
W/WindowManager( 1935): Frames: containing=[0,0][480,764] parent=[0,0][480,764]
display=[0,0][480,764]
W/WindowManager( 1935):     content=[0,0][480,764] visible=[0,0][480,764]
W/WindowManager( 1935): Cur insets: content=[0,0][0,0] visible=[0,0][0,0]
W/WindowManager( 1935): Lst insets: content=[0,0][0,0] visible=[0,0][0,0]
W/WindowManager( 1935): WindowStateAnimator{4175e098 com.embarcadero.testapp/com
.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity}:
W/WindowManager( 1935):   mSurface=Surface(name=com.embarcadero.testapp/com.emba
rcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity, identity=722)
W/WindowManager( 1935):   mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING mLastHidden=true
W/WindowManager( 1935):   Surface: shown=false layer=21025 alpha=1.0 rect=(0.0,0
.0) 480.0 x 764.0
W/WindowManager( 1935): mExiting=true mRemoveOnExit=true mDestroying=false mRemo
ved=false
W/WindowManager( 1935): Current app token list:
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #5: Token{4147e918 ActivityRecord{40f37df8 u0 com.andr
oid.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #4: Token{40f8ba70 ActivityRecord{40f5a6e0 u0 com.andr
oid.settings/.Settings}}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #3: Token{41026c08 ActivityRecord{41066858 u0 com.andr
oid.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity}}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #2: Token{40fdb350 ActivityRecord{41065178 u0 com.andr
oid.systemui/.usb.UsbStorageActivity}}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #1: Token{412efc28 ActivityRecord{40f59780 u0 com.andr
oid.settings/.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity}}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #0: Token{411d1618 ActivityRecord{41301c10 u0 com.goog
le.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardActivity}}
W/WindowManager( 1935): Final window list:
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #0: Window{4118e328 u0 SearchPanel}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #1: Window{4102e078 u0 NotificationPanel}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #2: Window{40f5fc78 u0 SystemBar}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #3: Window{41207b30 u0 CompatModePanel}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #4: Window{41187228 u0 InputMethodsPanel}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #5: Window{4124bca0 u0 Keyguard}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #6: Window{410404a8 u0 InputMethod}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #7: Window{4130e7f0 u0 com.android.launcher/com.androi
d.launcher2.Launcher}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #8: Window{415a35a0 u0 com.android.settings/com.androi
d.settings.Settings}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #9: Window{413e70d0 u0 com.android.vending/com.android
.vending.AssetBrowserActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #10: Window{41270650 u0 com.android.systemui/com.andro
id.systemui.usb.UsbStorageActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1935):   #11: Window{40f526e0 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWall
paper}
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1083): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer
```

Comment: You should learn about the Logcat and Stacktrace next. -> http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: can you give details about values of attributes under <uses-sdk> tag of your AndroidManifest.xml of your project

Comment: i updated my question to include the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: does the tablet meet the minimum requirements for XE5 (ie ARM v7 NEON + GPU?). Run this [tool](http://delphi.org/2013/09/syscheck-for-xe5-compatibility/) to verify.

Comment: Then you should open a case at Qualitycentral as this is bug?

Comment: Please check out the list of [known supported devices](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) on the Delphi wiki, run the tests, and then update the wiki with your results.  Akaso DTA90 is not currently on the list.

Comment: Download CPU Identifier (free) from Google Play. I really suspect your GPU doesn't support the minimum features (Neon). What is the exact processor in your tablet? (For instance, my S3 has a Snapdragon S4 MSM8960 x2, while my Nexus 7 has a Snapdragon S4 Pro APQ8064-1AA x4. Both have Adreno GPUs that are NEON capable.) The app I mentioned gives you this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, from your logcat, that despite the manifest containing a permission to write to external storage, your device is still not permitting it, perhaps due to an absence of external storage (or simulated external storage):

```
W/ContextImpl( 7014): Unable to create external files directory
```

I don't recall just now what it is that causes Delphi startup to want to write stuff, however if you remove the StartupCopy unit from the project fiule uses clause, yuo may see a difference in logcat....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing an Ad-Hoc build via Eclipse, (Run As -> Android Application), just open the LogCat View (Window -> Show View -> Other, Android > LogCat) and post the error traceback that you get on the crashing tablet.

It's very possible that the Android version is wrong, or it doesn't have enough memory, or you are using a feature that is not available, but we won't know without the traceback.

Comment: The question is tagged Delphi XE5 and Delphi, so it's not in Eclipse. :-)